# add_theme_support is not working on functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

While developing a new theme on Wordpress, I just noticed that add_theme_support is not working for me. I called `<?php wp_head();?>` before the head ends and `<?php wp_footer();?>` before the body ends. I am using Wordpress version 4.1.1. Can anyone help me sorting this out? I am tired after trying so many times but no luck :(

Answer (score 4):

On which hook did you add `add_theme_support`?
Please try `after_setup_theme` hook like the example below:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_function_after_setup_theme');
function my_function_after_setup_theme() {
    add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
}
```

Comment: I didn't use any hook. I just simply used these codes on the functions.php file :-

 add_theme_support('title-tag');
 add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array('default-image' => 'images/header.png') );
add_theme_support('custom-background');

None of these is working

Comment: I see. It should be called in functions.php or it should be hooked to after_setup_theme. (check the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support)

Can you please add your calls to the function above?

Comment: Thanks. My problem is resolved. You guys are very helpful. I always get help when I post anything in stackoverflow =D

Comment: Welcome, if it is worked for you then please vote for my answers it's valuable for me :)